# Check checkbox if function returns true in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a couple of checkboxes for available cars and I need to figure out whether they have to be checked if the user has rented any of the cars.

So I have an array of all available cars called $scope.cars and each user has got an array called cars $scope.user.cars. But I cannot figure out how to call the function on each checkbox checking whether the user has rented a car

```
<label ng-repeat="car in cars">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="hasRented({{car}});"> {{car.name}}
</label>

   $scope.hasRented=function(car)
    {
       var x= _.keys($scope.user.cars).contains(car.id);
       return x;
    }
```

Btw, I am using the function _keys from underscore.js to extract the keys from the $scope.cars-array.

What am I doing wrong ?

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling the function inside `ng-checked`, you don't need interpolation `{{ }}`:

```
<label ng-repeat="car in cars">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="hasRented(car)"> {{car.name}}
</label>

   $scope.hasRented=function(car)
    {
       var x= _.keys($scope.user.cars).contains(car.id);
       return x;
    }
```

Since `ng-checked` is a directive, the function is executing in an angular context already.